# Get the specified input parameter from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I want to get all the related information from database. For example I have a summary column which contains data like "A01.1 | Foodland Inbound QIP Details and Pre Unloading" and I want to pass only "A01" in input parameter and get all the data related to "A01"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far (stored procedure code!), including sample data and desired result. Also if you encountered errors, share that info too.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * from TableName where summary_column like 'A01%';
```

Comment: I would go for SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE summary_column like 'A01.%'.Otherwise everything that start with A01 will be returned and OP may not want it.Eg : - A010.1 will get selected

Comment: _I want to pass only "A01" in input parameter and get all the data related to "A01"_ as the question stands, the answer looks legit

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your comment, the where clause will only find a summary that is the equal to `A01.2` e.g:

`TaskMaster.Summary =@summary`

You want to use `LIKE` and a wild card:

`WHERE TaskMaster.Summary  LIKE '''' + @summary + '%' + ''''`

The above will find everything that starts with `A01.2`, so if you want to find all with `A01`, pass `@summary` as `A01`